# How to test a function in ps with test explorer in vsc

Tags: powershell, testing, pester

I want to set up powershell script testing but also limit the scope to functions. `myscript.ps1` contains internal functions with each their own parameter dependencies also, but I will not test them, only interested in `Get-Something`.

- How do I import the function from the script to my test without running the script?

myscript.ps1

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Script with functions.
#>

Param (
    [string]$myVar,
    [string]$myVar2
)
function Get-SomeThing {
    Param (
        [string]$myVariable,
        [string]$myVariable2
    )

    $foo = "$($myVariable) $($myVariable2)"

    return $foo
}
function Get-SomeThingElse {
        Param (
            [string]$myVariableAgain,
            [string]$myVariableAgain2
        )
        $bar = Get-SomeThing -myVariable $myVariableAgain -myVariable2 $myVariableAgain2
    
        $foo2 = "$($bar) $($myVariable) $($myVariable2)"
    
        return $foo2
}

Get-SomeThingElse -myVariableAgain $myVar -myVariableAgain2 $myVar2
```

my.Tests.ps1

```
Describe 'My Tests' {
    BeforeAll {
        $myVar = 'Hello'
        $myVar2= 'World'
    }
    It 'Test Hello World' {
        (Get-SomeThing -myVariable $myVar -myVariable2 $myVar2) | Should Be 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

directories

```
Root/
-Tests/
--my.Tests.ps1
-myscript.ps1
```

Comment: Have you considered packaging your functions/scripts as a module? This would allow for functions to be easily imported without execution

Comment: No I have not. What do I need to change in that case?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should think about building a module for these functions. As a stop gap before you get to that complexity, I would create a separate ps1 file that just contains the function definitions you want to test, and dot source them into `myscript.ps1` and `my.Tests.ps1`

```
Root/
-Tests/
--my.Tests.ps1
-myscript.ps1
-myscriptfunctions.ps1
```

to dot source `myscriptfunctions.ps1` from `myscript.ps1`:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot/myscriptfunctions.ps1"
```

to dot source `myscriptfunctions.ps1` from `my.Tests.ps1`:

```
. "$(Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent)/myscriptfunctions.ps1"
```

I like this pattern because for quick and dirty functions, I just declare them in `myscript.ps1`. As my code matures, and I need to test/make the functions better I move them into `myscriptfunctions.ps1` and can write some quick tests. And then if I continue to use the function, I can put them into one of my modules where I ostensibly have better tests/CI infrastructure to ensure these functions are the most reliable.